# Two fields in a Typescript object from string to float

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an object with different fields. I want to parse the long and lat from string to float. This code works, but I would like to know if there is a more elegant (better practice) way to achieve the same transformation.

```
this.data.forEach(element => {
    element.lat = parseFloat(element.lat.toString());
    element.long = parseFloat(element.long.toString());
});
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would use the function `Number`

```
Number(value?: any): number
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

```
this.data.forEach(element => {
    element.lat = Number(element.lat);
    element.long = Number(element.long);
});
```

Comment: This does not have exactly the same semantics as `parseFloat()`, which works on strings like `50.5deg` while this would result in `NaN` instead.

Comment: This saves me the need to add .toString()